# Why are my croissants heavy?

Tags: baking, bread, pastry

I have been experimenting with croissants and found that, delicious as they are, they are dense, not light and fluffy.  The layers are very close together, not open with vast pockets of air.

I have tried cranking up the oven to 550 when I initially put them in to get that "bloom", but that only adds a little.

One thing I have not tried is reducing the amount of butter and adding water - but I am following the recipes.

Also, what should the bakers' percentages be for a good croissant dough?

I have tried a dozen or more recipes, most from French bakers, but my dough usually turns out very dry, very stiff, nothing like that shown in the videos.

Comment: Please edit and add detail on the exact recipe and method you are using.

Comment: It may be that you have too many folds - May be worth watch French Guy cooking for some tips! [The Perfect Croissant](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=H-O-TocmrI4&list=PLURsDaOr8hWVg1jqcuf-XnejIMZp_eNxv&index=11 "youtube")

Comment: This is using any of a dozen or so recipes.  Depending on the recipe I end up with 27 or 36 layers.

Comment: The answer and comments on your previous question about brioche dough may be relevant: https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/108449/why-is-my-dough-sweaty. What kind of flour are you using? The stronger the better. Also may I ask, do you regularly make less rich breads with success? Jumping straight to croissants without much experience would be very ambitious ...

Comment: Are you using an electric oven?  They're dryer (as burning hydrocarbons produces water), so you might need to spray some water in the oven so you can get sufficient rise before they've set.  I'd actually consider turning *down* the heat, so the butter melts and steams before the outside is fully cooked.  (but I'm not a baking expert, so if someone else contradicts me, go with whatever they say)